# Built.io upload progress - android

Tags: android, built.io, built.io-backend

I want to show progress of my file upload. I use built.io to store my files, but really don't know how I can show progress, because I think built.io does not support this.

This is how I send file:

```
 final BuiltFile builtFileObject = new BuiltFile();
    builtFileObject.setFile(tempFile.getPath());
    builtFileObject.save(new BuiltResultCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(BuiltError builtError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"blad zapisu pliku",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAlways() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using "onProgress"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the current SDK provided by built.io. There is a plan to support this in the future.

A workaround is to call built.io using the REST APIs (check out the `REST` section on https://docs.built.io/guide#uploads). The regular HTTP upload call can then be tracked to get the progress detail.

Please mail us at support@built.io if you have any more queries with this! Glad to help.